# Diferencia Tupla y constructor

Tags: java, clase

Estaba con una duda con respecto a las tuplas y a los constructores en java. Por ejemplo si tengo una tupla yo la declaro en java asi (supongamos de auto) Auto<M,P> sus variables son String M = "ford","chevrolet", etc. y p = un entero que es el peso. ok, si tengo declarada esa clase como una tupla y ademas hago un constructor que recibe los mismos parametros, que diferencia o para que creo de esa forma la clase Auto (<M,P>) y no solo auto y creo el mismo constructor y le paso un String marca y un int peso? Estoy con java.

Comment: podrias mostrar el codigo donde implementas esto? como que tenes declarada una clase como una tupla? o es una clase o es una tupla...

Answer (score 0):

"ademas hago un constructor que recibe los mismos parametros"
" que diferencia o para que creo de esa forma la clase Auto (<M,P>) y no solo auto"

Me centraré en esas dos oraciones para resolver el problema de fondo.

La diferencia de crear un objeto auto , o un objeto auto(<m,p>) o auto(x,y,z) .
es indiferente , diria yo , ya que en java , tu puedes tener varios constructores en la misma clase auto .( y esto no toca , ni tiene nada que ver con polimorfismo , herencia que tocan el tema de constructores , esto quiero recalcar , no tiene nada que ver con esos temas , es algo propio de las clases de java poder tener varios constructores , segun tengo entendido)

Me explico , puedes crear 100 objetos autos por ejemplo , que sean tuplas no definidas que se reciban como parametro , sea con valores null , 0 , o cualquier valor aleatorio . Salvo sea el caso que dicho objeto venga con los valores ya asignados , el objeto se puede crear de muchas maneras y aún asi preserva sus caracteristicas y variables que pueden ser definidas luego.

En resumen yo no encontré diferencia, espero que hayan más respuestas.